# Spring SOAP webservice endpoint with Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-ws

I am developing a webservice using spring soap implementation and hence my service class is annotated with @Endpoint annotation. Now, I want to use SPRING AOP for application logging which I have already implemented. However, as I have noticed, until I execlude my service class from the pointcut expression, I get no endpoint mapping found exception when my webservice is invoked. When I exclude the service classes from AOP's scope, things work fine again. Any idea on this?

**UPDATE:**

**My logger class**

```
package com.cps.arch.logging;

@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Centralized Payment System");

    @Before("(execution(* com.cps..*.*(..)) and not execution(* com.cps.service..*.*(..)))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        logger.info("Execution Start : "+"Class: "+joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()+
                "Method: "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
```

}

**My Service Endpoint:**

```
package com.cps.service.impl;

@Endpoint
public class EndpointIntegrationServiceImpl  implements EndpointIntegrationService
{
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.com/cps/model";

    @Autowired
    public MYBO myBO ;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SaveDataRequest")
    public void saveData(@RequestPayload
            SaveDataRequest data) {
        //business layer invocation
    }
}
```

**My WS Configuration**

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.cps"})
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "MyWsdl")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("MyPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.example.com/micro/payment/PaymentManagement");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(reconciliationSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema schema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("XSD/MySchema.xsd"));
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(validationInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    ValidationInterceptor validationInterceptor() {
            final ValidationInterceptor payloadValidatingInterceptor = new ValidationInterceptor();
            payloadValidatingInterceptor.setSchema(new ClassPathResource(
                    "XSD/MySchema.xsd"));
            return payloadValidatingInterceptor;
        }
}
```

Sorry but I had to change few of the variable/class names to adhere to company policy.
So as you can see I had to put the "not execution" part in the AOP to make my webservice work. If I remove that part, I get 404 error.

Comment: Could you please show the code examples for the 2 situations you describe?

Comment: @Zergleb: Please see my update for the code

Answer (score 2):

@Tarun is right, though I also found it necessary to delay the initialization of the `AppConfig config` bean.

Because the `CustomValidatingInterceptor` bean in your (@hudi's) example is an `EndpointInterceptor`, it is needed early in the Spring initialization sequence.  This means it is being instantiated before the Aop weaving against the `config` bean has taken effect.  Note how there is also an `EndpointInterceptor` in the original question here.

One way to avoid this is to use an `ObjectFactory`.  This can be wired in from the start, but enables Spring to delay the actual instantiation of the `config` bean, until after the interceptor and Aop proxy are both well initialized.

There's an example of this back on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075048/1794485).  This tested fine from SoapUI.

Comment: thx a lot man. You saved my weekend. Bounty is your in 6 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

So below is the code you shared

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.aspect.PersistentAspect;
import org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class WsConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/v1/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema schema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("country.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        String[] jaxbContext = new String[] { "io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service" };
        marshaller.setContextPaths(jaxbContext);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        // aop not working
        //interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), config()));
        System.out.println("Loading addInterceptors");
        interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), null));
    }

    @Bean
    public AppConfig config() {
        System.out.println("Loading config Bean");

        return new AppConfig();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Bean
    public PersistentAspect persistentAspect() {
        System.out.println("Loading persistentAspect Bean");
        PersistentAspect persistentAspect = new PersistentAspect();

        return persistentAspect;
    }

    @Bean
    public Object testAop(AppConfig config) {
        System.out.println("is config aop proxy: " + AopUtils.isAopProxy(config));

        return config;
    }
}
```

You mentioned that it doesn't works with

```
interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), config()));
```

But works with

```
interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), null));
```

The issues when you call `config` manually, the bean is initiated by you and not by Spring and it somehow interferes. You should not initiate the class using the bean method `config()` instead use the class directory

```
interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), new AppConfig()));
```

And it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring a `PayloadLoggingInterceptor`

Check out section "5.5.2.1. PayloadLoggingInterceptor and SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" in the [Spring Reference Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html)

Comment: I am using configuration with annotation in spring boot. This is just spring

Comment: A great thing about Spring is "if you can configure it with XML, you can configure it with code".

Comment: yea but not so easy because in spring boot there is a lot of magic. And when something works in spring, spring boot just remove aop proxy with no warning as in my updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072312/why-enablews-removed-aop-proxy-from-spring-bean