# Adding custom ValidationInterceptor using @EnableWs will cause to stop working aop on my @Configuration bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-ws

I follow [this](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-intercept-request-response-soap-messages/) example to create custom validation interceptor. 
My interceptor is complicated and need to autowire some configuration. Method in configuration class are annotated to invoke some aspect. When I enable annotation `@EnableWs` and `@Autowire` my configuration into this interceptor, there is no more proxy created with my configuration class so aspect is not invoked. All I can debug is just that there is different order of initialization bean after this change. Any thoughts why is this happening ?

Later I can provide some code with example if there is not enough information

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492267/spring-soap-webservice-endpoint-with-spring-aop)  about this problem which is also not answered

**UPDATE:**

code add to repo: https://github.com/hudi1/aop-test

interesting part is overriding method:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    // aop not working
    interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), config()));
    // aop working
    // interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), null));
}
```

where you can see then I use config in my custom interceptor aop stop working on this class

Comment: Possible to provide a minimal git repo with the non working code

Comment: project created on git: https://github.com/hudi1/aop-test

Comment: So one things is confirmed that the issue is not because of what you pass to the validator. You can reproduce the issue when you create a new AppConfig in that function. That creates the problem